# Set MAX_POLL_RECORDS_CONFIG dynamically in Kafka

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

In Kafka the default MAX_POLL_RECORDS_CONFIG is 500. That is at maximum 500 messages can be pulled at a time. Is there any way to set this value dynamically based on the message size?
If message size is 50B then 1MB/50B should be the value assigned.

Answer (score 0):

The value must be set when you create a consumer client. It cannot be modified on a record-per-record basis "dynamically", no.

You can do math in any property value, however.  But that'll be static while using the same consumer instance

Answer (score 0):

If what you want to limit is the batch size in bytes instead of the number of records, you can set the `FETCH_MAX_BYTES_CONFIG` instead and set `MAX_POLL_RECORDS_CONFIG` to a large/unreacheable value (i.e. unlimited).

Note that `FETCH_MAX_BYTES_CONFIG` actually affects the underlying fetching behaviour, not just what is returned from each call to `poll()`.